# Can I recreate an object after really_destroy! it ? I do not want to recover it but create a new object with same email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-paranoia

I am using paranoia 2.4.2. I have used really_detroy! to "really destroy" a user. Now I am failing with recreate it in my database.

I did:

`Student.create(email: "blabla@bla.com", profile: 342)`

Error message is:

`Student Exists (8.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "students" WHERE "students"."email" = $1 AND "students"."deleted_at" IS NULL LIMIT $2  [["email", "blabla@bla.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]`

Does anybody know what is going on ?

Thx.

Comment: Do you have unique index on `email`?

Comment: What does 4.2 mean?

Comment: Sory I will correct it. It is Paranoia 2.4.2

Comment: Are you sure that's the error message? It looks like the SQL operation under the hood of Student.create . . .

Comment: Can you update the question with a reproduce example? Create the user - really_detroy! and then try to create a new user. Otherwise we are just guessing about whats really going on.